# Change of homeAsUpIndicator icon in ActionbarSherlock does not effect in ICS?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I try to change the `homeAsUpIndicator` icon in the `ActionBar`. I use `ActionBarSherlock` to be compatible with older Android Versions. I set a specific theme to my Activity when the App runs on a device with Older verions of ICS and ICS it shows different colors.

This is the style i am using

```
<style name="Theme.PM" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">

    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back_sign</item> 
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back_sign</item>

</style>
```

like this below image's 
For ICS  see that home as up indicator look like black color.

[image]

For Older versions of ICS  see that home as up indicator look like white color.

[image]

i am using same image for both versions, but it's looking different on ICS. how to solve this problem..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="CustomStyleUpAsHome" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarUpAsHome</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/arrow_home</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/arrow_home</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBarUpAsHome" parent="CustomActionBar">
        <item name="android:displayOptions">homeAsUp|useLogo|showHome</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">homeAsUp|useLogo|showHome</item>
    </style>

</resources>

<activity
    android:name=".activity.Activity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/CustomStyleUpAsHome">
</activity>
```

This code works great. Try to do something like that. May be it will help you.

Good luck!

Comment: hi, if i am using your code.. it gives error for this parent "CustomActionBar" . No resource found for this parent. Can you guide . i want to change back button image.

Comment: Hi. CustomActionBar is style that extends default actionbar theme. For example <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar"> , if you are using compatibility library or you can extend Sherlock or Platform themes. Good luck!